# Adding Top parent to existing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a problem with my SQL-Statement. I want to add the Top Parent of each object to each row. I tried a few things but I have to say that I'm pretty much a SQL beginner.

For example:

```
Object A: ID 2, ParentID NULL
Object B: ID 10, ParentID 2
Object C: ID 25, ParentID 10
Object D: ID 51, ParentID 25
```

Now the result should be:

```
Object D: ID 51, ParentID 25, TopParent 2
```

Here is my query so far:

```
With
  Geraetetypen(TypID, Typname, ParentID, Ebene) As (Select parentTyp.ID,
      parentTyp.geraeteTyp,
      IsNull(parentTyp.parentID, 0) parentID,
     1 As Ebene
From test_table_GeraeteTyp As parentTyp
Where parentTyp.parentID = 0
Union All
Select childTyp.ID,
  childTyp.geraeteTyp,
  childTyp.parentID,
  gt.Ebene + 1 As Ebene
From test_table_GeraeteTyp As childTyp
  Inner Join Geraetetypen As gt On childTyp.parentID = gt.TypID)
Select *
From
Geraetetypen
```

Right now I get ID, name, ParentID and level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the top query, then just echo it down the recursion:

```
With
  Geraetetypen(TypID, Typname, ParentID,       Ebene, TopParent) As (Select parentTyp.ID,
      parentTyp.geraeteTyp,
      IsNull(parentTyp.parentID, 0) parentID,
     1 As Ebene,
     parentTyp.ID TopParent                                                       
From test_table_GeraeteTyp As parentTyp
Where parentTyp.parentID = 0
Union All
Select childTyp.ID,
  childTyp.geraeteTyp,
  childTyp.parentID,
  gt.Ebene + 1 As Ebene,
  gt.TopParent                                                                     
From test_table_GeraeteTyp As childTyp
  Inner Join Geraetetypen As gt On     childTyp.parentID = gt.TypID)
Select *
From
Geraetetypen
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d4dcb/5)